# Laravel - recoger el valor de un datepicker en un controlador y usarlo con eloquent como condición

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

Desde una plantilla blade tengo dos datepicker para hacer un filtro de datos que recojo el valor desde jQuery de esta forma

```
  var date_start =  $('#dp_start').val();
  var date_end =  $('#dp_end').val();
```

En el controlador lo recojo via request de esta forma

```
    public function listWithFilters(Request $request) : Response
{
    $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $date_start = $request->input('date_start');
    $date_end = $request->input('date_end');

    $registers = Register::where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->WhereDate('date','>=', $date_start)
                ->WhereDate('date','<=', $date_end)
                ->orderBy('date')
                ->get();

    return $registers;

}
```

El valor que recibo desde Javascript són estos para las fechas 02/04/2018 y 02/04/2030 respectivamente.

EN cambio en la BD mi campo es de tipo datetime y tengo registros como estos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema esta que en la consulta que he puesto anteriormente del controlador no se como hacer el whereDate ya que tal como esta no me funciona.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Al recibir los datos en el controlador pasa tus variables por [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) y dales formato a lo que necesitas:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
public function listWithFilters(Request $request) : Response
{
    $user_id = $request->input('user_id');
    $date_start = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->input('date_start'))->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');
    $date_end = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->input('date_end'))->format('Y-m-d h:i:s');

    $registers = Register::where('user_id', $user_id)
                ->WhereDate('date','>=', $date_start)
                ->WhereDate('date','<=', $date_end)
                ->orderBy('date')
                ->get();

    return $registers;

}
```

Lo importante está en dos partes, inicialmente `Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $request->input('date_start'))` parsea el contenido de tu variable que es solo un string y con el formato que especificas en el primer parámetro y te retorna un objeto de Carbon con la representación de una fecha, la segunda parte `->format('Y-m-d h:i:s')` toma ese objeto de Carbon y lo transforma en un string con el formato proporcionado.

Comment: Muchas gracias , eso es lo que buscava

Comment: Relacionado con esto, cuando hace el return $registers me devuelve las "fechas" con el formato americano como puedo hacer en el response modificar el formato de las fechas?

Comment: @ilernet puedes igual parsearlo con carbon y formatearlo a como lo quieras mostrar